# Are there any trade restrictions between the fourth generation Pokémon games?

Tags: pokemon-fourth-generation, pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver, pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum

In particular, are there any restrictions between Pokémon Diamond/Pokémon Pearl and Pokémon SoulSilver/Pokémon HeartGold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no trade restrictions between gen 4 games. I have traded from HG and SS to Platinum.

For D/P/P

- You must have received the Pokedex from Professor Rowan at Sandgem Town

For HG/SS

- You must have received a Pokedex from Professor Oak at Mr. Pokemon's house (North of Cherrygrove City)

You would need 2 DS consoles and then just head to the Union Room, found in the Pokemon Centre, on both games and trade from there. 
You will need 2 Pokemon in your party to be able to trade.

Issues arise when trading between generations (gen 3 to gen 4, for example) as Pokemon, their Moves and their Held Items, may not exist in the past or future.

Comment: AFAIK; the only restrictions for transferring are **no HM moves** (Pal Park [G3 -> G4], Transfer Lab [G4 -> G5]) and **no held items** (Transfer Lab [G4 -> G5]). After Gen 1/2's time capsule, transferring has been one-way - and some Pokemon can only learn some moves in previous generation games, and must be transferred from that game to have the move in a newer game. (see [Delibird's Serebii page](http://serebii.net/pokedex-sm/225.shtml), the "Transfer Only Moves" section near the bottom.)

Comment: I'm aware of the one way transferring. I added the Pokemon restriction in the last paragraph because (if I remember correctly) you can still trade from Gen 2 back to Gen 1 if the Pokemon, Type and Moves existed in Gen 1.